# C++ XE 5 Application and C++ Builder 5 dll compatibility

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe5, c++builder-5

I have BCB5 dll with method:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SM(TDataSource *DS) {

 TForm *form = new TForm(Application);
 form->Width = 300;
 form->Height = 300;
 form->Name = "frm";

 TDBGrid *grd = new TDBGrid(form);
 grd->Parent = form;
 grd->Name = "grd";
 grd->Align = alClient;
 grd->DataSource = DS;

 form->ShowModal();

}
```

When I call this method from C++ builder 5 application, it's working fine.

```
try {
 typedef void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SM(TDataSource *DS);
 SM *Upload;
 HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary("main.dll");

 Upload = (SM*) GetProcAddress(hDll,"SM");
 Upload(DataSource1);
 FreeLibrary(hDll);

}
catch (Exception *ex) {
  ShowMessage(ex->Message);
}
```

But, if I'm trying to call this method from C++ XE 5 application, I get Access Violation.

Is there a way to solve the problem of data transmission from XE 5 application to BCB 5 dll without recompile dll in XE5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not safe to pass/use RTL/VCL objects over the DLL boundary like you are doing, unless both EXE and DLL are compiled with Runtime Packages enabled so that they share a common instance of the same RTL and VCL frameworks (but then you have to deploy the RTL/VCL BPL binaries with your app).

Your DLL doesn't work in XE5 because the DLL is expecting the BCB5 version of the `TDataSource` component, not the XE5 version.  No, they are not compatible, as they have different memory layouts and dependancies.

So your choices are to either:

1. recompile the DLL in XE5, and live with the risk that passing `TDataSource` over the DLL boundary is not safe in general, unless you enable Runtime Packages.
2. re-write the DLL to *be* a Runtime Package (BPL) instead.  Then passing `TDataSource` between EXE and DLL is safe.  However, Runtime Packages are version-specific, so you will need to compile separate BPLs if you need to continue using the code in both BCB5 and XE5.
3. re-write the DLL to not pass a `TDataSource` over the DLL boundary to begin with.  Figure out another interop-safe way to exchange data between EXE and DLL.